# How to get the Channel's list from youtube api?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to get all channel's list and it's statistics from the youtube api.

What I have done is:

1. Registered console app
2. Used Oauth Client Id
3. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list using this api I am getting all the statistics

This is what I am doing to get the channel's list

```
function requestUserUploadsPlaylistId() {
  // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
    mine: true,
    part: 'statistics'
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
    requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
  });
}
```

But , the problem is this return's only one channel's information. I have 20 channel's under my account. So, I need them all to display them in my table.

I have also tried to add **forUsername:'Username'** parameter but no success.

Also, when I tried to set **managedByMe:true** its returning error as

```
Global:"required",
Message:"Required"
```

Can't get any way to display the all channel's list. Can you please explain me?

This is what I want

```
Channelname ViewsCount
1               50
2               51
```

and so on.....

Ignore my code `response.result.items[0]` I am checking whole response in console. and items contains only one channel at a time.

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 1:**

When you use the `managedByMe` flag (set to `true`), you have to provide the required parameter `onBehalfOfContentOwner` for that flag, which is a string of the content owner Identifier that you have to know.

To get the proper content owner id, you need to request a new access token, and when logging in select the proper user that corresponds to the content owner id that you want to use, and things should work fine.

looking into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050537/cms-channel-list-using-youtube-api-with-onbehalfofcontentowner) it seems what you need to do is login as the CMS user account, and then you will use that user id as the content owner id, things should work afterwards as you need

---

**Initial answer:**

You are only accessing `items[0]` in your code which will only show one element, try changing the code to use a `foreach` loop and iterate over all the channels like this:

```
function requestUserUploadsPlaylistId() {
  // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
    mine: true,
    part: 'statistics'
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
     response.result.items.forEach(function(anItem) {
        playlistId = anItem.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
        requestVideoPlaylist(playlistId);
     });
  });
}
```

Regarding the other error, you cannot user `managedByMe` and `mine` at the same time, if you want to user `managedByMe` you need to clear out `mine` and have the proper permissions, I would recommend playing with the [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it) first to confirm everything works, then implement the code that reflects that, it's more descriptive errors there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. first, I am checking response only contains array length 0 which is not I want. Also, I am removing mine and then using the other parameters. Any other thoughts?"

Comment: What do you mean by "I am checking response only contains array length 0 which is not I want" ? if array length is 0 then you won't see any results, in your case you're seeing one result, which means the array can't be 0

When you run my code , what do you get ?

Comment: I mean items contains length 1 whatever I use as a parameter. Items[0] means I am accessing the first item from the array.

Comment: Ok, I need you to go here and fill in the same parameters you use in your code, and tell me if you still get only one item there or more:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it

Comment: Ok that seems to be a missing param/permission, can you remove `managedByMe` completely and set `mine` to `true` ? just want to see what comes out of that

Comment: {
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/1s-CO5YYBhh1GXXqVNCBasyf1DM\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"5g01s4-wS2b4VpScndqCYc5Y-8k/D0-zsVOkvyDtPrhxYsMBdQ99zYg\"",
   "id": "UCRLZVeQOAm0N6woLZS1eenw",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "64",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "0",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "3"
   }
  }
 ]
}

Comment: This is the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118193/discussion-between-just-code-and-mostafa-torbjorn-berg).